# Can Media Projection api take a screenshot from my home screen on lollipop?

Tags: android, screenshot, android-5.0-lollipop

Still not understanding if this is possible without root or not.I think that if it is possible to record the screen on video, this is also possible, have anyone done it yet?

[Been learning some code from this project, but still nothing](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-ScreenCapture)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check some code from [here](https://github.com/mtsahakis/MediaProjectionDemo). This code save bitmaps from the surface view related with Media Projection.

Comment: If that worked for you, would you accept your own answer please?